# batch rename to change only single character

Tags: unix, file, file-rename

How to rename all the files in one directory to new name using the command mv. Directory have 1000s of files and requirement is to change the last character of each file name to some specific char. Example: files are

```
abc.txt
asdf.txt
zxc.txt
...
ab_.txt
asd.txt
```

it should change to

```
ab_.txt
asd_.txt
zx_.txt
...
ab_.txt
as_.txt
```

Comment: This is not something that 'mv' itself can do. You're going to need to program it, probably using shell scripting. Thus, it would be useful to specify *which* shell you're trying to solve this problem in, since scripting differs between shells.

Answer (score 2):

You have to watch out for name collisions but this should work okay:

```
for i in *.txt ; do
    j=$(echo "$i" | sed 's/..txt$/_.txt/')
    echo mv \"$i\" \"$j\"
    #mv "$i" "$j"
done
```

after you uncomment the `mv` (I left it commented so you could see what it does safely). The quotes are for handling files with spaces (evil, vile things in my opinion :-).

Answer (score 2):

If all files end in ".txt", you can use `mmv` (Multiple Move) for that:

```
mmv "*[a-z].txt" "#1_.txt"
```

Plus: `mmv` will tell you when this generates a collision (in your example: abc.txt becomes ab_.txt which already exists) *before* *any* file is renamed.

Note that you must quote the file names, else the shell will expand the list before `mmv` sees it (but `mmv` will usually catch this mistake, too).

Answer (score 1):

If your files all have a .txt suffix, I suggest the following script:

```
for i in *.txt
do
    r=`basename $i .txt | sed 's/.$//'`
    mv $i ${r}_.txt
done
```

Comment: This doesn't look as if it replaces the letter before the period with the underscore.

Comment: I didn't actually know basename could do that (thanks for the education), but the solution is flawed - it adds the underscore rather than replacing the last character.

Answer (score 1):

Find should be more efficient than `for file in *.txt`, which expands all of your 1000 files into a long list of command line parameters. Example (updated to use bash replacement approach):

```
find . \( -type d ! -name . -prune \) -o \( -name "*.txt" \) | while read file
do 
    mv $file ${file%%?.txt}_.txt
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it a definite requirement that you use the `mv` command?
The perl `rename` utility was written for this sort of thing. It's standard for debian-based linux distributions, but according to [this page](http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-bulk-rename-files-in-linux-in-the-terminal) it can be added really easily to any other.

If it's already there (or if you install it) you can do:

```
rename -v 's/.\.txt$/_\.txt/' *.txt
```

The page included above has some basic info on regex and things if it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work with thousands of files, but in bash:

```
for i in *.txt; do
   j=`echo $i |sed 's/.\.txt/_.txt/'`
   mv $i $j
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash's `${parameter%%word}` operator thusly:

```
for FILE in *.txt; do
   mv $FILE ${FILE%%?.txt}_.txt
done
```